# Problem with cache key when using two different ways of pagination

Tags: pagination, apollo, react-apollo

I have an overview screen where events are shown per day in a paginated list. The list uses Apollo with `fetchMore` which is triggered when the end of the list is reached.

The default view of the list is a calander view which uses a moving date range to paginate through time. This works great.

The list of events will be shown as a simple list when the user uses a filter. This list view will base it's pagination on `limit` and `offset`.

**Problem**

Problem is that the pagination data which the calendar view uses is also part of the `keyArgs` of that field (user can filter with a date range). The results is that the calendar view will not load any other page because the query will be seen as a new cache query.

How can I make this work between the two lists?

PS: We use the `@Connection` directive to set the `keyArgs`. The field policy for this field holds only a merge function.

**Query**

```
query getEvents (
  $status: StatusEnum, 
  $limit: Int = 20, 
  $offset: Int = 0, 
  $happenedBetween: DateRangeInput
) {
    me {
        id            
        events(
          status: $status, 
          limit: $limit, 
          offset: $offset, 
          happenedBetween: $happenedBetween
        ) 
        @connection(key: "myEvents", filter: 
          [
            "status",
            "happenedBetween"
          ]
        ) 
        {
            ...ShowFragment
        }
    }
}
```